# Connecting second montor trough USB-C to DVI adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, usb-c

I have a problem in connecting a second monitor.
My laptop has only a HDMI plug and I need to use a DVI cable. To do so I bought a USB-C to DVI/VGA/HDMI/USB3 adapter.

Unfortunately it does not work. If I plug a USB stick to the adapter this is immediately recognized (so I guess that the adapter itself works and my linux system “sees” it) but I tried with HDMI, VGA and DVI and with none of them it works. The laptop do not recognize at all any screen.

I tried the adapter with a windows computer and with a MacBook PRO and works just fine with both of them.

The adapter is [this one](https://www.gearbest.com/cables-connectors/pp_1434948.html?wid=1433363&currency=EUR&vip=4265332&gclid=CjwKCAjw6djYBRB8EiwAoAF6ob7cn8Ne9TOYI8cD171LLxoaBqa8qTVu_gDoMH7_YbzDx2OF--KEQBoCs0cQAvD_BwE)!

My laptop is a Tuxedo InfinityBook PRO.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.13.0-43-generic)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This is my system log file after connecting the adapter:

```
guido@guido:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.409134] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.409145] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.409154] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d10] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.409160] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.482887] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.484264] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.485636] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03] is released
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.485709] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04-38] is released
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.485804] pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39] is released
Jun  6 14:36:04 guido kernel: [  508.485865] pci_bus 0000:02: busn_res: [bus 02-39] is released
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.142588] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:15da] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.142713] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.142714] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154386] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:15da] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154539] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154541] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154660] pci 0000:02:01.0: [8086:15da] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154806] pci 0000:02:01.0: supports D1 D2
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154808] pci 0000:02:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.154923] pci 0000:02:02.0: [8086:15da] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155071] pci 0000:02:02.0: supports D1 D2
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155073] pci 0000:02:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155218] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155228] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155235] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155305] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155315] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155377] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155387] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155394] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155470] pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15db] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155509] pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9f0ffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155693] pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155694] pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155868] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155878] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155910] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155943] pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155954] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155957] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155967] pci 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 2000
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155972] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x4000-0x5fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155978] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155980] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155982] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x4000-0x4fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155984] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155988] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155990] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155992] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.155998] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156008] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156011] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x4000-0x4fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156017] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156021] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156028] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156031] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156037] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156046] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156049] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x4000-0x5fff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156055] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156059] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156102] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156644] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.156883] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.157328] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.157334] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158712] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x00009810
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158843] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158846] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158848] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158849] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.13.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.158851] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159039] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159050] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159157] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159162] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159165] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159202] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159204] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159206] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159207] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.13.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159209] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159371] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido kernel: [  530.159381] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido systemd[1]: Reloading Laptop Mode Tools.
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido systemd[1]: Reloaded Laptop Mode Tools.
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido laptop-mode: Laptop mode
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido laptop_mode[5369]: Laptop mode
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido laptop-mode: enabled, not active [unchanged]
Jun  6 14:36:26 guido laptop_mode[5369]: enabled, not active [unchanged]
Jun  6 14:36:35 guido kernel: [  539.762066] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.905729] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6544
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.905734] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.905737] usb 3-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.905741] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.905744] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 0019B931DF2EC8C135AA01E2
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.906508] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido kernel: [  539.906819] scsi host1: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1"
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido systemd[1]: Reloading Laptop Mode Tools.
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido systemd[1]: Reloaded Laptop Mode Tools.
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido laptop-mode: Laptop mode
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido laptop_mode[5442]: Laptop mode
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido laptop-mode: enabled, not active [unchanged]
Jun  6 14:36:36 guido laptop_mode[5442]: enabled, not active [unchanged]
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.930854] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.931585] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.931977] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 3911616 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.932130] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.932133] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 65 44 09 30
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.932278] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.932285] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.933802]  sda: sda1 sda2
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  540.935592] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido systemd[2579]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Ubuntu\x5cx2016.04.4\x5cx20LTS\x5cx20amd64.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Ubuntu\x5cx2016.04.4\x5cx20LTS\x5cx20amd64.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda and /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Ubuntu\x5cx2016.04.4\x5cx20LTS\x5cx20amd64.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Ubuntu\x5cx2016.04.4\x5cx20LTS\x5cx20amd64.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda and /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2018\x2d02\x2d28\x2d19\x2d15\x2d18\x2d00.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2018\x2d02\x2d28\x2d19\x2d15\x2d18\x2d00.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda and /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido systemd[2579]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2018\x2d02\x2d28\x2d19\x2d15\x2d18\x2d00.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2018\x2d02\x2d28\x2d19\x2d15\x2d18\x2d00.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda and /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  541.303527] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  541.305902] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido udisksd[3033]: Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/guido/Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64 on behalf of uid 1000
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido kernel: [  541.306971] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
Jun  6 14:36:37 guido gnome-session[2820]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
^C
guido@guido:~$
```

Output of lsusb

```
guido@guido:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:3410 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
guido@guido:~$
```

Comment: What Display driver do you use? Does the connection work with another driver?

Comment: Please disconnect you adapter. Then open terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in it, then connect your adapter to USB port. Wait for its detection and copy all output you get to the question ([edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1043761/edit) it). Output of `lsusb` will be useful too.

Comment: @CyrillC , I don't know how to check it and how to change it.

Comment: @N0rbert , I don't k now why I have not been notified of your comment, I have just done it.

Comment: @GuidoVallerotto if you re problem is solved, don't put the *[solved]* in title, just make an answer and mark it as solved later (it can help other people later if someone else will have the same issue)

Comment: @damadam, ok sorry. As far as I see Melebius already did this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem [solved by @GuidoVallerotto](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1043761/3).

> I solved the problem: in order to make the adapter work, I had to go in the bios in `Advanced Chipset Control` and change the `Display Digital Interface` (DDI) control from `DDI` to `mDP` (mini Display Port) to `DDI` to `TBT` (Thunderbolt).
>
> Now, of course, if I would use the `mDP` I should switch back to `DDI` to `mDP`.

Comment: I can't find this setting in Bios. I have a "Lenovo ThinkPad P15 G1". Using a USB-C monitor Works but the USB-C to DVI Monitor does not work.